# cocoa:how webview disable the scrollbar

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

webview disable the scrollbar
Two -finger scrolling, I would like to ban .

Like this can not

```
[[webView windowScriptObject]evaluateWebScript:@" document.body.style.overflowX='hidden';"];
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] setAllowsScrolling:NO];
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow scrolling in one dimension only? I'd specifically like to disable horizontal scrolling.